# add navigation below logo

Tags: html, css

I need to have logo in the top center of screen. Under logo I need navigation bar.

I have the following css:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: url(images/bg_image.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;      
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Verdana;
    color: #ffffff;
}
    #header {
    background: url(images/logo2.png);    /* THIS IS LOGO IMAGE IN CENTER*/     
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center 20px;    /* CENTERING AND TOP MARGIN IS 20PX*/
    height: 180px;      
}
/* NAVIGATION BAR */
#top-nav{       
    border:0px solid #ccc;      
    list-style:none;    
    /*margin-top:135px;*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;              
    background-color: #000000;
}

#top-nav li {       
    display:inline;
    width:130px;
}

#top-nav a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}   

#top-nav a:hover{
    background: url(images/selected_menu.png);      
    background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
```

and HTML

```
   <body>

    <div id="header">           
        <ul id="top-nav">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        </ul>           
    </div>
            ....
```

This gives me Logo in the center and top. But navigation bar goes on the logo. I need it to be under logo (it should be 135px from the top of the screen). 
If I add margin to #top-nav margin-top: 135px then logo also is moved by 135px. What is the proper way to solve this?

I guess this is a simple question, but this is the first time I am slicing psd to html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add padding to the Header div element something like `padding-top:135px`

Answer (score 0):

You shoul seperate your logo from your nav in something like this

```
<header>
   <div id="logo"></div>
  <ul id="top-nav">
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   </ul>  
</header>
```

and give your logo `width:100%` and that background-image.